# Group records equally by 3 or n value using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to equally divide record by 3 in SQL. Please refer on below example.

```
DocNos   SiteCode  SiteName   
11111    0001      Canada
11111    0002      Australia
11111    0003      China
11111    0004      Japan
11111    0005      India
11111    0006      Brazil
11111    0007      England
11111    0008      Italy
```

Desired Output

```
DocNos   SiteCode  SiteName     Group
11111    0001      Canada        1
11111    0002      Australia     1
11111    0003      China         1
11111    0004      Japan         2
11111    0005      India         2
11111    0006      Brazil        2
11111    0007      England       3
11111    0008      Italy         3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function like `row_number` with some arithmetic. Change the denominator per the desired group size.

```
select t.*,1+(row_number() over(partition by docnos order by sitecode)-1)/3 as grp
from tbl t
```

Comment: does this `(row_number() over(partition by docnos order by sitecode)-1)/3`  return integer rather than 1.33 1.66 ....

Comment: @nikhilsugandh . . . Yes.  SQL Server does integer division.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `NTILE()` window function:

```
SELECT
  *,
  NTILE() OVER(ORDER BY DocNos, SiteCode, SiteName) AS Grp
FROM table;
```

Another way, using CTEs (common table expressions) and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH total_rows AS (
  -- Count total rows
  SELECT COUNT(*) row_count
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  *,
  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DocNos, SiteCode, SiteName) / row_count) AS INT) AS Grp
FROM table
CROSS JOIN total_rows;
```

**Further reading:**

- Ranking Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- `NTILE()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- `ROW_NUMBER()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017